# Use GPU for PIL in python on mac (macOS Catalina)

Tags: python, macos, gpu, python-imaging-library, macos-catalina

I optimized my code to process images with pillow. It uses all the sources to get as fast as possible. Just the GPU would make it faster. I don't find any solution beside CUDA and that wont't work on Catalina. Is there any way to use my GPU(NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M 2 GB
Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB) to make the process more efficient?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: What does your code do? Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to give a specific example of the thing you want to make faster. It needs to be small, self-contained, and you need to give a link to any necessary input data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no way to use pillow to do that! If you need a better speed, you can use ImageMagick (Wand as python wrapper) or GraphicsMagick (pgmagick as Python wrapper). If you need to use GPU, ImageMagick gives some option to use it if possible (I am not sure about GM) but it is not neither as efficient nor complete as you use CUDA or OpenCL. I recommend you to use Vulkan if you need better result and cross platform (Nvidia and AMD, MacOS, Linux Windows...).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should work for now, even if its not the perfect solution for my problem.